# Debugger Status in Xcode Console

Tags: xcode, gdb

I have a query regarding Debugger Status 
like The Debugger has exited With status 0
The Debugger has exited With status 1 and so on 
What are the Status of the Debugger ??

Based on which criteria Status can be Categorized ?? 
Please Let me know different kinds of status and its usages 
what are the consequences happen when we get the STATUS of application

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the [Xcode Debugging Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/000-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007057-CH1-SW1)?